# MongoDB - Too Many Connection Error

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have developed chat module using node.js() and mongo sharding and gone live to production server. But today its reached 20000 connection in mongodb and getting error "Too many connection" in logs. After that we have restarted the node server and started again. now its comes normal. But we have to know how will solve this problem immediately.

Any configuration are there to set it in mongodb to kill the connection if not used or set the expire time while establish the connection.

Please help us to close this issue.

Regards,
Kumaran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not running into a MongoDB issue. There's a cap to the amount of connections you can make to MongoDB that's usually roughly equal to the maximum number of file descriptors available to it.

It sounds like there is a bug in your code (likely) or mongoose (less likely) that either creates more connections than it closes or never closes connections in the first place. In Java for example creating a new "Mongo" class instance for each query would result in this sort of problem but I don't work with node.js/mongoose so I do not know what the JS equivalent of that is.

Keep an eye on mongostat and check to see if the connection count always increases or if it decreases sometimes. If it's the former your code never releases connections for whatever reason. If it's the latter you're simply creating them faster than idle connections are disconnected. That's usually due to doing something heavy weight (like the driver initialising it's connection pool) for every query rather than once.

Comment: Exactly correct what you are saying. We found this issue and fix it. Thanks for your immediate reply.